# Supplying a JS function for extern function in Emscripten WebAssembly module exported with "MODULARIZE=1"?

Tags: emscripten, webassembly

When using the MODULARIZE=1 option with emcc, is there a way to supply a function for the extern *sendToJs* function:

**emcc compile command**

```
emcc test.cpp -O3 -s WASM=1 -s MODULARIZE=1 -o test.js
```

**test.cpp**

```
...
extern void sendToJs(int num);
...
```

**Javascript**

```
const Module = require('test.js');

Module({
        wasmBinary: wasmBinary,

        // I was hoping this kind of thing might work:
        env: {
            _sendToJs: num => console.log('fromWasm', num)
        }
    })
    .then(...);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be working:

**Javascript:**

```
Module({
    wasmBinary: wasmBinary,

    // Override instantiateWasm
    instantiateWasm: (info, receiveInstance) => {
        info.env._sendToJs = (num) => console.log('sendToJs', num);

        WebAssembly.instantiate(wasmBinary, info)
            .then(response => receiveInstance(response.instance))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));

            return true;
        }
})
.then(...);
```